# SSH key added to the user gets deleted after log out

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to run ssh -T git@gitlab.com to test my connection to gitlab.

I'm able to connect to gitlab using ssh-key when I log in to the machine and run this via command line. (in same user context as Jenkins and same working directory as Jenkins)

But, I'm not able to connect to the Gitlab via ssh from Jenkins once I log out and log in again.

Here are the things I'm doing:

For login, the user is `Jenkins` but it's in ec2 instance. So, after logging into ec2 instance, I'm doing `sudo su jenkins` to log into Jenkins user.

Once I log in, I'm adding the ssh-key using following commands:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add <mySshKey>

ssh -vT git@gitlab.com
```

The output I get is:
`Welcome to GitLab, @vighneshpai!`

But, when I use `exit` to log out and log in again and try `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com` it fails. Says `Permission denied (publickey)`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Your interactive session succeeds after `debug1: Offering RSA public key: gitlab-key`, your non-interactive session fails when it does not offer that public key. Presumably this means you don't have that key given to the non-interactive session, perhaps because you are not using an SSH agent to pass the key. You probably want to use a machine-specific key instead, and have your Jenkins have access to, and use, that key rather than one from an agent.

Answer (score -1):

add your Jenkins public key to gitlab account

Comment: As I already told you, it working fine when I manually connect from my machine and do an ssh connection. So that implies that I have added key onto my account :)